# How to identify time when a binary variable first equals 1?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame:

[image]

I am looking to create a new column that identifies the first time that the binary variable is equal to one. So the above table would become:

[image]

How can I accomplish this? Can it be done in dplyr?

```
structure(list(Time = c("12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", 
"5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00"), BinaryVar = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), FirstTime = c("3:00", "3:00", 
"3:00", "3:00", "3:00", "3:00", "3:00", "3:00", "3:00", "3:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `match` which returns the index of occurrence of 1st value.

```
df$FirstTime <- df$Time[match(1, df$BinaryVar)]
df

#    Time BinaryVar FirstTime
#1  12:00         0      3:00
#2   1:00         0      3:00
#3   2:00         0      3:00
#4   3:00         1      3:00
#5   4:00         1      3:00
#6   5:00         1      3:00
#7   6:00         1      3:00
#8   7:00         1      3:00
#9   8:00         0      3:00
#10  9:00         0      3:00
```

You can write the same in `dplyr` as following -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(FirstTime = Time[match(1, BinaryVar)])
```

---

The benefit of using `match` is when you don't have 1 in `BinaryVar` it would return `NA`'s.

```
df %>% mutate(BinaryVar = 0, FirstTime = Time[match(1, BinaryVar)])

#    Time BinaryVar FirstTime
#1  12:00         0      <NA>
#2   1:00         0      <NA>
#3   2:00         0      <NA>
#4   3:00         0      <NA>
#5   4:00         0      <NA>
#6   5:00         0      <NA>
#7   6:00         0      <NA>
#8   7:00         0      <NA>
#9   8:00         0      <NA>
#10  9:00         0      <NA>
```